# Why is economic profit for a monopoly per unit demand minus ATC?

Tags: monopoly

[image]

I understand that the P-ATC gives the per unit economic profit

Why is this the case? Why wouldn't we take price minus the marginal cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price minus marginal cost gives you ***marginal profit***.

\begin{align*}
\text{Total profit}&=\text{Revenue}-\text{Total cost}\\
\frac{\text{Total profit}}{\text{Quantity}}&=\frac{\text{Revenue}-\text{Total cost}}{{\text{Quantity}}}\\
&=\frac{\text{Revenue}}{{\text{Quantity}}} - \frac{\text{Total cost}}{{\text{Quantity}}}\\\\
\text{Per-unit profit}&=\text{Price}-\text{Average total cost}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, this working you showed isn't for magrinal profit, right?

Comment: And why is revenue per quantity price?

Comment: When you want to figure out what your revenue (basically total income) is, you multiply the quantity you sell by the per-unit money you get from selling, aka. price. The demand curve is the *relationship* between price and quantity demanded by the consumers.

Comment: But isn't quantity you sell multiplied by per unit money you get QR, not Q/R?

Comment: Let's call "per-unit money" price. What I said was Q*P = Revenue. So Revenue / Q = P.